# PHP: possible to set constants in default php.ini file

Tags: php, apache

I want to have a constant (a string) that is available to all PHP-scripts on the server.

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php this is quite easy if you parse an extra .ini file, however I don't want to parse an extra file, I want to set my constant in the global php.ini without having to parse anything in the scripts. (In fact that's the whole point because I need the constant to find the stuff to include/parse/etc: When I know where this extra .ini file would be, I don't need it anymore!)

Just inventing a new constant in php.ini and then trying to access it with ini_get() does not work, is there any other way?

I compile Apache and PHP myself, so I could also set the constant at compile-time and/or use Apache-constants if that is neccessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a PHP [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) script in your PHP ini to do this as it will be run before any of your user-land scripts:

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the
>   main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require
>   function, so include_path is used.

So you can add an ini line like:

```
auto_prepend_file="/home/user/script.php"
```

The in /home/user/script.php:

```
define('CONSTANT_NAME', 'your nice value here');
```

Now in your PHP scripts you can access `CONSTANT_NAME` from wherever you like as it is available in all PHP scripts.

I use this technique on my staging server that uses mod_rewrite based mass virtual hosting so I can give my PHP scripts an accurate document root. I have discussed this in a [blog post before](http://blog.simonholywell.com/post/1516566788/team-development-server#virtual_document_root).

Comment: Unfortunately it is as close as you are going to get. What you want is not actually possible ):

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Create a file xxx.php where you define your constant and add that file to the global [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) in php.ini. I would like to add though that keeping this kind of global constants or variables is not a recommended way of working as you may forget where are the constants coming from and is not making your apps very portable and explicit to other developers.

Comment: The Include Path contains directories, not files.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said I think you'll find that there will already be something similar already available in [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), in particular 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'.

Comment: Exactly, I need something very similar to DOCUMENT_ROOT (but not DOCUMENT_ROOT, which is the whole point of this question)

Comment: @Robby75 that is exactly what I am using the solution in my answer to achieve on my staging server: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10751734/461813