# Defining constants in PHP on MAMP OSX setup

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I have a MAMP setup on my OSX. I'm following advice from the thread here:

[PHP: possible to set constants in default php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751688/php-possible-to-set-constants-in-default-php-ini-file)

I have found the correct php.ini file and added this bit under the directories section:

```
auto_prepend_file = "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/constants.php" //standard MAMP setup URL
```

Then, in constants.php:

```
define(‘ABS_PATH’, '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs');
```

However, for example on a simple include, ABS_PATH is not defined (and thus shows up as ABS_PATH if I put the below URL in a variable and echo out the result)

```
<?php include ABS_PATH."/includes/file.php"; ?>
```

Am I missing something specific to MAMP, or just a small error somewhere? I feel like I'm following the above post advice exactly as stated. Thanks.

Comment: I hope you aren't using `‘` and `’`.... PHP doesn't like smart quotes

Comment: Do you mean changing constants.php to define("ABS_PATH", "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"); ? It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256008/setting-environment-variables-in-mamp
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't ever get this to work out of MAMP's php.ini. However, this post:

[Automatically load a config.php file for all pages before anything else.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14884439/automatically-load-a-config-php-file-for-all-pages-before-anything-else)

explained that you can use auto_prepend_file in a .htaccess file in your root directory and it will accomplish the same thing.